# How to create json response from django orm annotate?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-orm, django-serializer

I want to create sales per month report and send it to the frontend.

here is my serializers.py:

```
from .models import Sale
from rest_framework import serializers


class SaleSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Sale
        fields = ['url', 'id', 'date', 'sku', 'product', 'quantity', 'price']
```

Here is the view from views.py:

```
from django.db.models import Sum
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view
from rest_framework.response import Response
from .serializers import SaleSerializer
from .models import Sale

@api_view()
def monthly_sales(request):
    monthly_sales = Sale.objects.values(
        'date__month').annotate(Sum('price'))
    serializer = SaleSerializer(
        monthly_sales, many=True, context={'request': request})
    return Response(serializer.data)
```

When I go to browser I get the Attribute error:

```
 'dict' object has no attribute 'pk'
```

What's the solution?

Answer (score 0):

No need to serialize, just pass the `monthly_sales` to `return Response(monthly_sales)`:

```
@api_view()
def monthly_sales(request):
    monthly_sales = Sale.objects.values(
        'date__month').annotate(Sum('price'))
    serializer = SaleSerializer(
        monthly_sales, many=True, context={'request': request})
    return Response(monthly_sales)
```